# mvn package not recognizing OS environment variables

Tags: java, maven, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy an API do AWS EC2.

And this API has environment variables inside application.properties, such as $DB_HOST, $DB_USER and $DB_PASS, and then I set them at

```
vim .bashrc
source .bashrc
```

All the process occurs alright for the deployment, but when I run

```
sudo mvn package
```

It doesn't recognize the environment variables setted from the OS (linux) and build fail.
I can't really find any similar solution here.

Also tried putting them inside the /˜profile with

```
nano /˜profile
source /˜profile
```

Anyone has any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `sudo`, it doesn't use *your* environment variables but those of the root user (or in case you use `sudo -u <user>`, that user).

I suggest not using `sudo` without specifying a user. That means that the code is running as root, which is a big security risk. I'd create a new user dedicated for your application. You can configure that user's environment variables as well.

Comment: I understand! thank you very much for the response! 

This would fix the issue? Because if even in the root user it doesn't build, on other specific it would?

Sorry I'm quite new to Linux

Comment: The user  that is used for the build should have the environment variables defined that are needed to make the build succeed. So if you have user `myapp`, then user `myapp` should have these environment variables defined, and you should run `sudo -u myapp mvn package`.